# Update a launcher app c#

Tags: c#, auto-update

I'm coding a launcher.exe file that will check client version and update client (a game).
My idea is run launcher-> download version file from host -> check ver -> download new update(.zip) -> extract to client->start
But now i want to also update that launcher.exe by that zip file
It is running, how to update it?
Please give me some advise.

Comment: Write a launcher updater as well.

Comment: but the Launcher is running, so that i can't rewrite the new launcher. because i want to open once.

Comment: I'm saying write a third program that updates your primary launcher. You can't have the program patch itself (not without an unbelievably complex system set up, anyway), so the simplest solution is to have an updater for your updater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I cameback here to talk about what I did to solve this

My launcher run like this:

`Launcher.exe` startup -> make it own clone `Launcher.exe.bin` -> `Launcher.exe` run `Launcher.exe.bin` -> `Launcher.exe` exit -> `Launcher.exe.bin` kill all `Launcher.exe` process-> start update process

Answer (score 3):

Since this topic has no answer yet, I post mine

I came up with the same situation for a personal project. I had a launcher which was in charge of checking and downloading new main application version and the main application itself. I finally decided to add a feature in the main app which was in charge of updating the launcher.

Prerequirement : the update package (imagine a ZIP file containing new version) contains the new launcher version with the name "launcher.exe_new"

- Start your launcher.exe. It will download the ZIP file
- Unzip the update package and put the "launcher.exe_new" in the same directory where your launcher is located
- Launch the main application freshly updated
- The main app will check whether a "launcher.exe_new" file exist. If so, delete "launcher.exe" file and rename "launcher.exe_new" in "launcher.exe"

Comment: you're idea is OK but I think you can do better. Let's  find out way that you don't need to run main application to update launcher.exe

Comment: Totally agree with u, I still don't be entirely satisfied with my own solution. Another way could be by using a third application like a simple bash script to perform the replacement... But the problem still the same : who launch the script ?